# Java. Склейка файлов

Tags: java, файлы

Учусь писать на Java, набросал код для склейки файлов(работает). Прошу указать в каких местах можно было бы сделать лучше(где я написал плохой код) + ответить на вопросы внизу.

Задание: Есть несколько файлов формата "filename.txt.partN". Ввести их имена с клавиатуры, затем создать в этом же каталоге файл "filename.txt" с последовательно записанными в нём данными. Имена вводятся в любом порядке. Ввод прекращается после ввода слова "end".

Так как в задании не нужно было проверять данные на корректность, проверок нет. Юзер "идеальный", только порядок файлов напутать может.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
            String fileName;
            String sub = ".part";
            String stopWord = "end";

            byte[] buf = new byte[4096];

            ArrayList<String> fileNameList = new ArrayList<>();

            while (!(fileName = reader.readLine()).equals(stopWord)) {
                fileNameList.add(fileName);
            }

            if (fileNameList.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Пустой лист.");
                return;
            }

            fileNameList.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> Integer.parseInt(o.substring(o.lastIndexOf(sub) + sub.length()))));

            OutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(fileNameList.get(0).substring(0, fileNameList.get(0).lastIndexOf('.'))));

            for (String partFile : fileNameList) {
                InputStream is;
                try {
                    is = new FileInputStream(partFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    System.out.println("Файл " + partFile + " не найден.");
                    return;
                }
                int count = is.read(buf);
                do {
                    fos.write(buf, 0, count);
                }
                while (count == buf.length);
                is.close();
            }
            fos.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

По вашему, ArrayList это правильный выбор? Или лучше было использовать TreeSet?

Если бы мне нужно было проверять каждый файл в списке, то что работало бы быстрее для разумного количества файлов: регулярка или сравнение с filename + sub?

Заранее благодарю.

Comment: ArrayList тут нормально подходит. Просто не пришлось бы сортировать лишний раз. И зачем ты такую сложную схему сортировки делал? Всей файлы имеют одно название и отличаются только последним числом, если просто сравнивать имена файлов как строки все будет работать замечательно.

Comment: Нет, если просто сравнивать строки(например fileNameList.sort(String::compareTo);), то при n> 10 будет неправильная сортировка, по моим представлениям потому что символов в этих строках будет просто больше.

Comment: Хм, да. А еще если прям все по феншую, то можно указывать только имя файла, а программа должна сама искать в папке все файлы с именами "fileName + ".part" + i"

Comment: цикл копирующий вызывает сомнения. Вы файл читаете вне цикла, а пишете в цикле. C Java 9 можно использовать [`InputStream::transferTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#transferTo-java.io.OutputStream-).

Comment: InputStream::transferTo кстати тоже прекрасно работает, спасибо. А что использовать предпочтительнее?